# ¿Cómo puedo ajustar la imagen al tamaño del div que la envuelve?

Tags: javascript, css, html5, css3

Lo que estoy intentando hacer, es ajustar la imagen que tengo en un `carousel` para que ésta no se muestre desproporcionada. Como se muestra actualmente es de la siguiente manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es mi código `css` que ajusta el `div` principal y la imagen como tal:

```
#demos .owl-carousel .item {
    height: 280px;
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    }


#demos .owl-carousel .item > img {
    position: relative;
    height: 16.5rem;

}
```

Lo que buscó es que la imagen sea proporcional al `div` que la envuelve, de antemano agradezco su ayuda.

Comment: _280px = 17.5rem_ según el cálculo hecho en https://nekocalc.com/es/px-a-rem-conversor. Intenta definir la altura a la imagen así: `height: auto;`

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda DjCrazy, probaré la solución.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si lo que quieres es que una imagen se ajuste al contenido de tu `div` lo que puedes hacer es agregarla como background al `div` en cuestión con la propiedad de CSS `background-image` y utilizar la propiedad `background-size: contain` que hará que la imagen se redimensione teniendo en cuenta el tamaño del div.

Te agrego un ejemplo en el cual hay dos `div` de diferente tamaño y en ambos añado la misma imagen como background . Como puedes observar, en los dos la imagen se redimensiona para ocupar el máximo tamaño posible del `div` sin pixelarse ni estirarse.

```css
.imagenContenida{
   background-image: url("https://miro.medium.com/max/1200/0*UEtwA2ask7vQYW06.png");
   background-size: contain;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

#imagen1{
   height: 100px;
   width: 300px;
}

#imagen2{
   height: 200px;
   width: 850px;
}
```

```html
<div id="imagen1" class="imagenContenida"></div>
<div id="imagen2" class="imagenContenida"></div>
```